# C# How to search property name recursively

Tags: c#

I need help to solve a problem, my problem is as follows, I have the following object

```
 public class Teste
 {
     public string Descricao { get; set; }
     public Time Time { get; set; }
 }
```

.

```
public class Time
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Time (string nome)
    {
        Nome = nome;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to obtain the complete path of a certain property.

```
var teste = new Teste();
teste.Descricao = "bar";
teste.Time = new Time("foo");
var b = GetProperties(teste, "Nome");
//expected return: "Time.Nome"
```

I was testing something I arrived at the following method

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> GetProperties(object obj, string propertyPath)
{
     var objType = obj.GetType();
     if (objType.IsValueType || objType.Equals(typeof(string)))
         return Enumerable.Repeat(Tuple.Create(propertyPath, obj.ToString()), 1);

     else
     {
         if (obj == null)
             return Enumerable.Repeat(Tuple.Create(propertyPath, string.Empty), 1);

         else
         {
             return from prop in objType.GetProperties()
                    where prop.CanRead && !prop.GetIndexParameters().Any()
                    let propValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null)
                    let propType = prop.PropertyType
                    from nameValPair in GetProperties(propValue,  string.Format("{0}.{1}", propertyPath, prop.Name))
                    select nameValPair;
         }
     }
 }
```

but it returns everything to me and I would like it to return a specific property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some issues with searching properties that come from system modules.  You have to decide which properties are worth recursively descending and which ones are not.  Also, you'll have to maintain a list of objects that you have already visited to ensure that you do not follow cycles.  I think a breadth-first search would be best, but for this example, I'll code a depth-first search.  Also, I just return the first match, not all matches, you can adjust as needed.  Furthermore, it returns a (mostly useless) string version of the path rather than a list of reflected properties that would be needed to actually access it (You'd have to do reflection again to locate the properties by name to retrieve the value from this "path" string.)

I'll start you off with a basic implementation.  Likely someone else can improve upon it.

```cs
static string GetPropertyPath(object obj, string name, List<object> visited = null)
{
    // does the object have the property?
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    var properties = t.GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties) {
        if (property.Name == name) {
            // that's it!
            return name;
        }
    }

    // if we get here, it's because we didn't find the property.
    if (visited == null) {
        visited = new List<object>();
        visited.Add(obj);
    }

    // Get all the properties of the first object and keep searching,
    // keeping track of objects we've visited already.
    foreach (var property in properties) {
        // Limit which kinds of properties we search
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(typeof(Program).Module, property.Module)) {
            // get the value of the property
            object obj2 = property.GetValue(obj);
            // Do not search any previously visited objects
            if (!visited.Any(o => object.ReferenceEquals(o, obj2))) {
                visited.Add(obj2);
                string path = GetPropertyPath(obj2, name, visited);
                if (path != null) {
                    // found it!
                    return property.Name + "." + path;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Example**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var teste = new Teste();
    teste.Descricao = "bar";
    teste.Time = new Time("foo");
    var b = GetPropertyPath(teste, "Nome"); // "Time.Nome"
}
```